# Proof of existence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove this:

> Consider a non-negative function $f$ defined on the unbounded interval $[1, \infty)$, on which it is monotone decreasing. Then the infinite series
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)
> $$
>   converges to a real number if and only if the improper integral
>   $$
> \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx
> $$
>   is finite. In other words, if the integral diverges, then the series diverges as well.

My thoughts：

I have proved that
$$
s_n -f(1) \lt \int_1^b f(x)\,dx  \lt s_n
$$
where  sn is the nth partial sum of f(n)

The convergence of sn can be proved bacause sn is bounded and increasing. but I have some trouble on the other direction

Comment: What did you try? What are your thoughts?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the proof of this theorem in the Wikipedia link posted by @PeterSzilas. It is fairly comprehensive.